# connections issue with jsPlumb on zoom in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

First I want to thank you Simon for this amazing plugin, I have been using it for a project I have and it looks amazing, I wanted to add a zooming function to my project which ended up in loosing the connections and their position, I read an older post where it stated that using Anchors of 1px will ignore this problem, but it didn't solve mine either, please have a look a the below code Im using to work with the zoom, and let me know what you think,

```
$("#main").css({
"-webkit-transform":"scale("0.75")",
"-moz-transform":"scale("0.75")",
"-ms-transform":"scale("0.75")",
"-o-transform":"scale("0.75")",
"transform":"scale("0.75")",
});
instance.setZoom(0.75);
<div id="main" style="float:right; background:url(images/white.gif);">

<div class="demo flowchart-demo" id="flowchart-demo" style="width:15000px; height:8125px; background:url(images/grid.png);">

  <div class="start dragwindow box" id="flowchartWindow1" style="left:42px; top: 46px;">    </div>
<div class="start dragwindow box" id="flowchartWindow2" style="left:82px; top: 86px;">    </div>
<div class="start dragwindow box" id="flowchartWindow3" style="left:102px; top: 106px;">    </div>
<div class="start dragwindow box" id="flowchartWindow4" style="left:152px; top: 156px;">    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by calling `instance.repaintEverything()` after `setZoom`.
This is of course not optimal performance-wise but in my case it was sufficient.